# Integer expression expected giving for below script in the if statement......This `expr $num%$i` gives % when used with echo...Why so?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a number"
read num
i=2
res=true
while [ $i -le $num ]
do
       if [ `expr $num%$i` -eq 0 ]
       then
               res=false
       fi
       i=`expr $i + 1`
done

echo "$res"
```

This `expr $num%$i` in if statement gives % when used with echo....Why so?

```
Enter a number
6
./4.sh: line 8: [: 6%2: integer expression expected
./4.sh: line 8: [: 6%3: integer expression expected
./4.sh: line 8: [: 6%4: integer expression expected
./4.sh: line 8: [: 6%5: integer expression expected
./4.sh: line 8: [: 6%6: integer expression expected
true
```

Why the expr is not evaluating as per modulo operator

Comment: Step one: Don't use `expr`, use normal shell arithmetic expansion.

Comment: Step two: run your scripts through https://shellcheck.net

Comment: `expr` requires whitespace between values and operators

Comment: The code uses several archaic features.  This modern-style code may do something like what you want: `read -r -p "Enter a number: " num; res=true; for (( i=2; i*i<=num; i++)); do if (( num%i == 0 )); then res=false; break; fi; done; echo "$res"`.  Note that, as a prime tester, it fails for inputs `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, separate the args and the operator with spaces, eg:

```
num=6
i=2

# wrong

$ if [ `expr $num%$i` -eq 0 ]; then echo 'equal'; fi
-bash: [: 6%2: integer expression expected

# right

$ if [ `expr $num % $i` -eq 0 ]; then echo 'equal'; fi
equal

# or

$ if [ $(( num % i )) -eq 0 ]; then echo 'equal'; fi
equal

# or

$ if (( num % i == 0 )); then echo 'equal'; fi
equal
```